# evernote: list notes in a book

Tags: vb.net, evernote

```
    ' Get a list of all notebooks in the user's account.
    Dim myNotebookList As List(Of ENNotebook) = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks()

    For Each item In myNotebookList
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Name)
    Next


    'Get a list of all the Notes in a NoteBook



    Dim mybook As ENNotebook = myNotebookList.Find(Function(i) i.Name = "april2014")

    For Each item In mybook
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
```

the first part works fine, getting the list of notebooks...but the second part does not work.

ok have changed my code to this....

```
   Dim mybook As ENNotebook = myNotebookList.Find(Function(i) i.Name = "april2014")

    For Each mybook In myNotebookList
        ListBox2.Items.Add(mybook.Name)
    Next
```

and now i get the list of all my notebooks again.

"april2014" is a notebook and i want to get the list of notes inside this notebook.

=================================

## NEW CODE

```
    ' Get a list of all notebooks in the user's account.
    Dim myNotebookList As List(Of ENNotebook) = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks()

    For Each item In myNotebookList
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Name)
    Next


    'Get a list of all the Notes in a NoteBook

    Dim mybook As ENNotebook = myNotebookList.Find(Function(i) i.Name = "april2014")




    Dim myfindbook As List(Of ENSessionFindNotesResult)



    myfindbook = ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(ENNoteSearch.NoteSearch(""), mybook, ENSession.SearchScope.Personal, ENSession.SortOrder.Normal, 10)




    If (myfindbook.Count > 0) Then
        For Each Result As ENSessionFindNotesResult In myfindbook
            ListBox3.Items.Add(Result.Title)
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: can anybody give me a clue as to what i am doing wrong.....

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the second part does not work" - you'll need to provide specific details as to what "does not work" means. What result are you expecting and what result do you get that's different from the expected one?  Do you receive an error message, and if so, what's the error code and/or text of the error message?

(Note that I would have entered this as a comment but I don't have sufficient points yet to comment.)

Comment: what i am trying to do is get a list of all the notes in a notebook. the error is Error 1 Expression is of type 'EvernoteSDK.ENNotebook', which is not a collection type..  this error is on "mybook" in the for each loop.

Comment: It sounds like `Dim mybook As ENNotebook = myNotebookList.Find(Function(i) i.Name = "april2014")` is working properly and returning the notebook named "april2014". However, **ListNotebooks** only returns a list of notebooks; it does not return the notes contained within those notebooks. After you find the desired notebook, you need an additional call to the Evernote service to retrieve its notes. That's done via the **FindNotes** method [which is documented here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/master/Getting_Started.md#finding-notes-in-evernote).

Comment: Dim myfindbook As List(Of ENSessionFindNotesResult) = ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(ENNoteSearch.NoteSearch("april2014"), Nothing, ENSession.SearchScope.Personal, ENSession.SortOrder.Normal, 21)
        If (myfindbook.Count > 0) Then
            For Each Result As ENSessionFindNotesResult In myfindbook
                ListBox3.Items.Add(Result.Title)
            Next
        End If
is this what you mean....nothing displays in the listbox

Comment: The ENNotebook object should be the second parameter in your FindNotes call - so it would be `Dim myfindbook As List(Of ENSessionFindNotesResult) = ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(ENNoteSearch.NoteSearch(""), mybook, ENSession.SearchScope.Personal, ENSession.SortOrder.Normal, 21)`

Comment: thanks, i am now getting a list of notes,BUT, not the correct notes. the i should be getting is all the note from notebook "april2014" . the list i am getting are from July. i have checked the notebook aprill2014 and it has only aprill notes in it.  have edited my orginal post to include my new code.

Comment: I ran a test and confirmed that `FindNotes` is working correctly. So two things: I notice that you're only retrieving the first 10 notes that `FindNotes` locates (the last parameter to that method); I'd suggest changing that to 100 or so and see what you get. Also, make sure that `mybook` is not null when you call `FindNotes`; my guess is that it's null and that would explain why you're getting notes which aren't in that notebook.